# Why is Spring used together with JSF? What does it offer?

Tags: spring, jsf

What is wrong with JSF only? Why are there many tutorials combining JSF and Spring? As far as  I know, JSF can be used alone for dynamic websites as well?

What is it that Spring puts on top of it?

Also, can Spring be used without JSF?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Spring can be used separately from JSF, in any type of application, not just web apps. Except for its web layer, Spring MVC, the functionality it brings to the table is largely orthogonal to what JSF is.

Spring started off as an [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container, and as a reaction to the perceived (and actual) complexity of older versions of Java EE. Much of what it brought to the table has been folded into current Java EE practices.

I'd consider looking at the Spring documentation and tutorials as "what it is" is fairly large in scope, but includes the afore-mentioned IoC/DI container, a web layer, a data access layer, several ways of handling enterprise integration, security, and so on.

Comment: A good overview. Though I would've used 'complementary' instead of 'orthogonal' :)

Answer (score 2):

Spring is not only a web framework. The web framework (Spring MVC) is only one part of Spring. Spring is also an [IoC container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), and has a lot of supporting libraries for stuff like database access, security, remoting and much more as well. So it's quite possible to use Spring together with JSF.

Answer (score 2):

Not to restate the wide variety of subprojects under the Spring umbrella mentioned in other answers, and all the facts related to the opportunity of Spring to be used not solely in web applications, I'd answer the part not covered by other answers, and that is its relation to JSF within a given project.

Both JSF and Spring offer a DI framework, though the former's managed beans are considered kind of 'basic'. Moreover, JSF beans were designed to serve at the presentation tier, more or less. They don't provide for an 'easy integration' with middle tier, and data tier, i.e. they are not transactional, don't implement declarative security, can't be remote, etc.

All those features are offered by, for example, EJBs. They require a full application server to function, so they are considered 'heavyweight'. Their functionality can be complemented by using CDI beans.

Spring offers a 'lightweight' alternative, as plain servlet container is enough for such an application to run. Spring offers *a means of handling middle tier and data tier*. For a JSF project that means that you will easily be able to implement declarative transactions, DAO support, etc.

JSF can, of course, be used *alone*, but boilerplate code, which is *really* error-prone must be handled on your own. Though, for small applications it could be enough.

In the end, Spring core can be thought of, *more or less*, as an alternative to EJBs within a web application.